# Getting an error when trying to import a component into Jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-thunk

I am using React+Redux/Redux-thunk and I am trying to implement jest/enzyme. I was able to successfully make a passing test for the root component. However I'm stuck at a point where I am trying to make a new test file for another component. No matter what component I try to test (connected or not connected) I am getting the same error.

```
 FAIL  src/views/LoginView/LoginView.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Expected the reducer to be a function.

      32 |   }
      33 | 
    > 34 |   const store = middleware(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);
         |                 ^
      35 |   const compressor = createCompressor();
      36 |   const persistor = persistStore(store, { transforms: [compressor] }, () => { store.getState(); });
      37 | 

  at createStore (node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:68:11)
  at node_modules/redux/lib/applyMiddleware.js:38:19
  at middleware (src/redux/configureStore.js:34:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/main.jsx:78:37)
```

I am not able to even write my first test as it errors out while importing the component.

The test file looks like this (pretty much blank) and it is in the same directory as the component LoginView.

```
import React               from 'react';
import { shallow }         from 'enzyme';

import LoginView       from './LoginView';

test('passing test', () => {

});
```

My jest.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js',

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',

    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^handsontable'      : 'handsontable',
  },

  modulePaths: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules',
  ],

  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(react-joyride)/)',
  ],

  globals: {
    __API_BASE__        : '',
    __HOT_BUILD_DATE__  : '',
    __HOT_PACKAGE_NAME__: '',
    __HOT_VERSION__     : '',
    __HOT_BASE_VERSION__: '',
    __BASENAME__        : false,
    __DEBUG__           : false,
  },

  verbose: true,

};
```

I'm using the following versions of everything:

```
"react": "^16.5.2",
"babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.0.0",
"enzyme": "^3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-persist": "^5.5.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux-raven-middleware": "^1.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
```

I would appreciate any feedback or guidance on this topic as I am currently unable to write any tests on my components other than my root component.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are importing something from main.jsx in your LoginView.jsx and it executes main.jsx code on this import step. Try `jest.mock('../../main.jsx')` in your LoginView.test.jsx after imports. If it does help, then you have to check why are you importing main.jsx and avoid the reason of import.